# undefined reference error in VScode Version 1.69.1

Tags: visual-studio-code

Below is simple program where i have configured VSCode on Azure VM with all applicable extensions to run c program

[image: Function reference at top for compiler]

But when i try to compile i am getting below error
[image: Undefined reference error]

[image: Installed Extensions]

Any hints or missing extensions will assist... if i define func() at top prior main() it works but would be interested to know how do i make it work the way i am trying too  ..any hints will be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your entire `void meow(void)` function definition:

```c
void meow(void) { 
    printf("meow\n"); 
}
```

outside of the `main()` function definition brackets `{ }` like so:

```c
int main(void) {
    ...
    ...
}

void meow(void) { 
    printf("meow\n"); 
}
```

Comment: HI Jeffrey worked like charm ..thanks for quick reply and assisting me to rectify my mistake..lesson learned..cheer's mate..

Comment: No worries. no need to upvote. It wasn't much. Accepted answer is enough